# BMP File line padding issue

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, bmp

So I'm trying to export a .bmp file in C++ code, and I have it working except for one major thing: line padding. I'm not 100% sure on how line padding works, but I know I need it. My algorithm works except for the padding, I manually added padding in a hex editor to my exported image and it worked. But how do I add padding? Here is what I have:

```
//Size of the file in bytes
    int fileSize = 54 + (3 * width * height);

    //The sections of the file
    unsigned char generalHeader[14] = {'B','M',0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,54,0, 0,0};
    unsigned char DIBHeader[40]     = {40,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 1,0,24,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0};
    unsigned char pixelArray[1000000];
    unsigned char bmpPad[3] = {0, 0, 0};

    //Set the binary portion of the generalHeader, mainly just file size
    generalHeader[2] = (unsigned char)(fileSize);
    generalHeader[3] = (unsigned char)(fileSize >> 8);
    generalHeader[4] = (unsigned char)(fileSize >> 16);
    generalHeader[5] = (unsigned char)(fileSize >> 24);

    //The binary variable portion of the DIB header
    DIBHeader[4]  = (unsigned char)(width);
    DIBHeader[5]  = (unsigned char)(width >> 8);
    DIBHeader[6]  = (unsigned char)(width >> 16);
    DIBHeader[7]  = (unsigned char)(width >> 24);
    DIBHeader[8]  = (unsigned char)(height);
    DIBHeader[9]  = (unsigned char)(height >> 8);
    DIBHeader[10] = (unsigned char)(height >> 16);
    DIBHeader[11] = (unsigned char)(height >> 24);

    //Loop through all width and height places to add all pixels


    int counter = 0;
    for(short j = height; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        for(short i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            //Add all 3 RGB values
            pixelArray[counter] = pixelColour[i][j].red;
            pixelArray[counter] = pixelColour[i][j].green;
            pixelArray[counter] = pixelColour[i][j].blue;
            counter++;
        }
    }

    //Open it
    ofstream fileWorking(fileName);

    //Write the sections
    fileWorking.write((const char*)generalHeader, 14);
    fileWorking.write((const char*)DIBHeader, 40);
    fileWorking.write((const char*)pixelArray, 3 * width * height);

    //NO MEMORY LEAKS 4 ME
    fileWorking.close();
```

pixelColour is of struct data type with the 3 colours, all type unsigned char. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case, each row must be a multiple of 4 bytes (32 bits).

```
int pad = 0; // Set pad byte count per row to zero by default.
// Each row needs to be a multiple of 4 bytes.  
if ((width * 3) % 4 != 0) pad = 4 - ((width * 3) % 4); // 4 - remainder(width * 3 / 4).
```

Padding values can contain pretty much anything, but it is best to set them to 0.  When you reach the end of writing each row, just write an additional `pad` number of zeroes (bytes) before writing the next row.

```
for(short j = height; j >= 0; j--) {
    for(short i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        //Add all 3 RGB values
        pixelArray[counter++] = pixelColour[i][j].red; // Need to advance counter.
        pixelArray[counter++] = pixelColour[i][j].green;
        pixelArray[counter++] = pixelColour[i][j].blue;
    }
    for (int padVal = 0; padVal < pad; padVal++) pixelArray[counter++] = 0; // Pad.
}
```

Finally, you need to write a larger file size:

```
fileWorking.write((const char*) pixelArray, (3 * width + pad) * height);
```