# Manually writing bmp image works for one resolution and is broken for other

Tags: c++, image, bmp

I try to create bmp output image. According to bmp header structure this code looks correct.
Bmp header structure was taking according to http://www.fastgraph.com/help/bmp_header_format.html
But it produced valid bmp image only for resolution 500x500px.  Whats wrong with code?

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <fstream>

struct BmpHeader
{
    uint32_t   mFileSize;        // Size of file in bytes
    uint32_t   mReserved01;      // 2x 2 reserved bytes
    uint32_t   mDataOffset;      // Offset in bytes where data can be found (54)

    uint32_t   mHeaderSize;      // 40B
    int    mWidth;           // Width in pixels
    int    mHeight;          // Height in pixels

    short  m_colorPlates;     // Must be 1
    short  mBitsPerPixel;    // We use 24bpp
    uint32_t   mCompression;     // We use BI_RGB ~ 0, uncompressed
    uint32_t   mImageSize;       // mWidth x mHeight x 3B
    uint32_t   mHorizRes;        // Pixels per meter (75dpi ~ 2953ppm)
    uint32_t   mVertRes;         // Pixels per meter (75dpi ~ 2953ppm)
    uint32_t   mPaletteColors;   // Not using palette - 0
    uint32_t   mImportantColors; // 0 - all are important
};

int main()
{
    uint32_t width = 2;
    uint32_t height = 2;

    std::ofstream bmp("1.bmp", std::ios::binary);
    BmpHeader header;
    bmp.write("BM", 2);
    header.mFileSize = uint32_t(sizeof(BmpHeader) + 2) + width * height * 3;
    header.mReserved01 = 0;
    header.mDataOffset = uint32_t(sizeof(BmpHeader) + 2);
    header.mHeaderSize = 40;
    header.mWidth = width;
    header.mHeight = height;
    header.m_colorPlates = 1;
    header.mBitsPerPixel = 24;
    header.mCompression = 0;
    header.mImageSize = 0;
    header.mHorizRes = 2953;
    header.mVertRes = 2953;
    header.mPaletteColors = 0;
    header.mImportantColors = 0;

    bmp.write((char*)&header, sizeof(header));

    for (unsigned int y = 0; y<height; y++)
    {
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x<width; x++)
        {
            typedef unsigned char byte;
            byte bgrB[3];
            bgrB[0] = 120;
            bgrB[1] = 120;
            bgrB[2] = 120;

            bmp.write((char*)&bgrB, sizeof(bgrB));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IIRC, each row has to be padded to a multiple of 4. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Pixel_storage

Comment: thanks, it fixed problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BMP File line padding issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440672/bmp-file-line-padding-issue)