# Hard-coded bitmap in c++ produces skewed lines

Tags: c++, image, bitmap

Im attempting to figure out how to draw straight vertical lines in a hard-coded bitmap file generated through c++:

```
#include <fstream>
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;



int main ()
{
   ifstream infile ("white8x8.bmp");
   ofstream outfile ("output.bmp");
   char c;
   cout << "Start of original read/write: " << endl;
   for (int i = 0; i <= 53; i++)
   {
      infile.read (&c, 1);
      cout << (int) c << ' ' << c;
      outfile.write (&c, 1);
   }
   char z = 0;
   char x = 0;
   int j_prev = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i <= 250; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j <= 250; j++)
      {

         if(j == 10){
           c = 0;
           z = 0;
           x = 0;
           outfile.write (&c, 1);
           outfile.write (&x, 1);
           outfile.write (&z, 1);
           j_prev = j;
         }
         /*if(j %250 == 0){
           c = 0;
           z = 0;
           x = 0;
           outfile.write (&c, 1);
           outfile.write (&x, 1);
           outfile.write (&z, 1);
         }*/
         else{
           c = 255;
           x = 255;
           z = 255;
           outfile.write (&c, 1);
           outfile.write (&x, 1);
           outfile.write (&z, 1);
         }
      }
   }

   cout << endl << "Start of read new file: " << endl;
   infile.close();
   outfile.close();
   ifstream out2 ("output.bmp");
   out2.seekg(53);
   int count = 0;
   for(int i = 53; i < 15000; i++){

     out2.read(&c, 1);
     cout << count << ":" << (int) c << ' ' << c;
     count++;
   }
   out2.close();
   return 0;
}
```

I would think that you could view the pixel array as a 2 dimensional array and that getting a horizontal line would only require plotting a pixel everytime j hit a specific number. This does not seem to be the case as doing so gives me a skewed line shown below.

[output.jpg](https://postimg.org/image/7a16nusgf/)

Just for clarification I am copying the bitmap header info from an already created bitmap, then simply creating an accompanying pixel array and modifying it from there.

Comment: BMPs must be padded to a multiple of 4 pixels.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440672/bmp-file-line-padding-issue

Comment: If the width of your image is not evenly divisible by 4 (or 8), then from what I remember, you have to make it so, otherwise you get a staircase effect.

Comment: @RetiredNinja 4 bytes, not 4 pixels.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  Been a while since I've had to write bmp reading or writing code. :)

Answer (score 4):

BMP files are required to be padded to a multiple of 4 bytes for each row. Your rows are 250*3=750, which is *not* a multiple of 4; 2 bytes are swallowed up for padding at the beginning of each row, causing it to be offset. Just write an extra 2 bytes of zeros at the end of your `j` loop.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding you but after inserting 2 bytes of zeros after the closing bracket of the else bracket I end up with a bmp that has skewed colors across the entire image?

Comment: @goetztyler sorry I wasn't clear. When I said "at the end" I really meant *after* the end.